# how to validate in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following application, I would like to show an error message if the customer already exists. I tried to do this by looping through the customer names but it does not seem to work. In other words, how can I check if customer name already exists using angular js?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
<script>
  //create an object that ties with module
  // pass an array of dependencies
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); 
  //create controller
  myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.customers = []; 
    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
      $scope.date = new Date();
      $scope.customers.push({
        name: $scope.customer.name
      });

      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.name.length; i++) {
        if(customers[i].name == name) {
          alert('Customer already exists'); 
        }
      }     
    };

    $scope.removeCustomer = function(index) {
      $scope.customers.splice(index,1);
    };
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in `for` statement.

Your code

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.name.length; i++) { ...
```

Should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) { ...
```

**EDIT 1**
I have add a full version of the validation based on your existed code:

```
$scope.addCustomer = function() {    
  var isExisted = false;  

  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
    if($scope.customers[i].name == $scope.customer.name) {
      isExisted = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isExisted) {
    // inform user
    alert('Customer already exists');
  } else {
    // save new customer
    $scope.customers.push({
      name: $scope.customer.name
    });

    // clear the input, maybe
    $scope.customer = {};
  }
};
```

**EDIT 2**

I have added my comments about your code:

- In the loop, your conditional logic `$scope.customers.name.length` is wrong. The correction is `$scope.customers.length`. You want to loop in array `$scope.customers`, right?
- Your conditional logic for checking existing is wrong, too. `customers[i].name == name`:  what are variable `customers` and `name`? They are undefineds. I think they should be `$scope.customers` and `$scope.customer.name`.
- After you found an existed customer, you should add `break` statement. No need to continue the loop, right?
- You should improve your code style. Pay attention at indent and semicolon.

Comment: Mr.d Thanks for the help, it is very clear now. I will make sure implement your advice as well in the future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate function to check and call that in the `add` function:

```
$scope.addCustomer = function(){
    $scope.date = new Date();

    if (doesCustomerExist($scope.customer.name) == false) {
        $scope.customers.push({
            name: $scope.customer.nam
        });  
    }
}

function doesCustomerExist(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.customers.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.customers[i].name == name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```